# Is there a way to edit a referenced cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Data

I have a Google Sheet with a column containing the following names:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Alice |
| Dan | Bob |
| Alice | Dan |

The values in `A` are raw text; the values in `B` are populated by the formula `=SORT(A:A)` written in cell `B1`.

## Question

Is there a way to edit the values in Column `B` and have those changes reflected in `A`, even though they are just references?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Idea: Use an edit / change trigger that does the change on A based on the cell edited in B.

Answer (score 1):

Try, with in B1 the formula `={"sorted list";sort(A2:A)}`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange()
  if (r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getRow() > 1) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    var values = sh.getRange('A1:A' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat()
    if (values.indexOf(e.oldValue) != -1) {
      sh.getRange(+values.indexOf(e.oldValue) + 1, 1).setValue(e.value)
    }
    r.clearContent()
  }
}
```